# Find all html elements in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering is there some way to find all html elements in one div and somehow count them?
In this example I am trying to get all elements and how many there are in element where I click on:

```
var divs = ($(e.target).find('div')).length;
var spans = ($(e.target).find('span')).length;
```

etc for every single one of them?

UPDATE: I don't know how to explain it better with words so:

```
<div id="someDiv">
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
<p></p>
<header></header><header></header>
</div>
```

Do I need to count them one by one or it is way to get all how many times:

```
span-4
p-1
header-2
```

Comment: Have you tried the asterisk * selector?

Comment: Not totally clear what objective is. Be more specific

Comment: Nop, even if I do it will tell me the number of all elements I need like divs: 10 spans: 11

Comment: Please provide a use case where you illustrate the sample HTML and your desired output.

Comment: I added something, look it that html that I added I use this ($(e.target).find('div')).length; to get each element length and I am asking is there way to look which elements are in div and to count them only not all elements length, which are in div and their each length

Comment: `var divs = $($(this).find('div')).length;`

Comment: @charlietfl answer is what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to count each type of element create a counter object using `tagName` as keys

```js
$('#someDiv').click(function() {
  var counts = {}
  $(this).find('*').each(function() {
    var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    counts[tag] = counts[tag] || 0;
    counts[tag] ++;
  });
  console.log('Header count=', counts.header);
  console.log(counts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someDiv">Click me
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
  <p></p>
  <header></header>
  <header></header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `this` and `length` like :

```
$('*', this).length;
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){
    console.log( 'I HAVE '+ $('*', this).length + ' CHILDS' );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>I'm DIV 1 (CLICK ME)
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <span>Child 2</span>
  <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>I'm DIV 2 (CLICK ME)
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <span>Child 2</span>
  <p>Child 3</p>
  <div>Child 4</div>
  <span>Child 5</span>
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

**To count every tag you could use `each()` :**

```js
$('div').on('click', function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var cbnames = [];
  
  _this.children().each(function() {
    if (!~$.inArray(this.tagName, cbnames)) cbnames.push(this.tagName);
  });

  $.each(cbnames, function(i) {
    console.log(cbnames[i] + ' = ' + $(cbnames[i], _this).length);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>I'm DIV 1 (CLICK ME)
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <span>Child 2</span>
  <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>I'm DIV 2 (CLICK ME)
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <span>Child 2</span>
  <p>Child 3</p>
  <div>Child 4</div>
  <span>Child 5</span>
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: Pff you missed the question, is there a way to find all elements in some div like:

<div id="someDiv"> <span></span><span></span><span></span> <p></p> <br> <header></header> </div>
And to check on click #someDiv how many elements are there and which elements are there

Comment: It is how many elements not each element how many times.. I wondered can I get all elements and how many times with some simpler code then to search for each to get their length

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` and `length` to count all elements inside the container:

```js
var num = $("#container *").length;
console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <div>3</div>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, which goes through all elements and counts them (grouped by tag name).

```js
var elements = {};
$('#someDiv').find('*').each(function() {
  var tagName = $(this).prop("tagName");
  if(!elements[tagName]) {
    elements[tagName] = 0;
  }
  elements[tagName]++;
});

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someDiv">
  <span></span>
  <span>
    <span></span>
    <br></br>
    <test></test>
  </span>
  <span></span>
  <p></p>
  <br>
  <header></header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use $('#someId').find('*') to get a list of the elements and then iterate over the results to get your data.